# Content created on VS Code doesnt show on github when I upload it?

Tags: html, github, upload

I was told to upload the html files that I already solved from VS Code to Github and thats what I did, but once it is uploaded it only shows the instructions, without my code.

When I upload files in github, they dont show with the code I created doing the exercise, it shows just the instructions? I always save the work on vs code, can anyone please help me understand why it shows just the instruction of the exercise and not the code I solved? TY

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.